# Conditional statement when it comes to date format

Tags: shell, unix

I have to validate the inputted date from the user. The accepted date format is '+%m/%d/%Y' (04/10/1999)

I also have to validate if the 1st parameter is greater than or equal to 2nd parameter which is also a date. For example: 10/04/2000 10/04/1999, this will echo '1st should be greater than 2nd'

`

```
#operational statement
if [ "$1" -gt "$2" ]; then
    echo "1st should be greater than 2nd"
    exit 255
fi #having error of integer expression expected 

#validate inputted date
if [ "$1"  -ne `date -d '+%m/%d/%Y'` ] || [ "$2" -ne `date -d '+%m/%d/%Y'` ];
then
    echo "Invalid. Follow [MM/DD/YY] Format"
    exit 255
fi #i think there is a mistake with my condition but can't figure it out.
```

Comment: You have to supply an argument to the `-d` option. If you just want the current date, drop `-d` altogether. If you want to compare dates as strings, you should use `%Y/%m/%d` (and consider dropping the unnecessary `/`s) instead. The shell doesn't know anything about dates as a specific type of data.

Comment: Just to be a little more specific as to something chepner alluded to -- `-ne` and `-eq` are only for integer arithmetic; they don't work in any other context. Use `=` and `!=` for comparing arbitrary strings.

Comment: And as a matter of good practice -- though it'll only bite you here if you have, say, `IFS=/` -- always quote your command substitutions. That is to say, ```"`date -d +%m/%d/%Y'`"```, _with_ the double quotes; that way it can't be split into separate words. Better still is to use double quotes _and_ use modern command substitution syntax; `"$(date -d '+%m/%d/%Y')"` is still guaranteed to work in all POSIX shells (present in the original early-90s POSIX.2 standard), and the implementation details are a lot less surprising.

Comment: BTW, think about switching to `YYYY-MM-DD` for dates; it's standardized, it's less regionally ambiguous (a lot of the world uses `DD/MM/YY`!), and it makes your strings' sort order match up with the semantic meaning (dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` sorted with regular string-sorting tools will be in the same order as with date-aware sorting tools, which isn't the case with `MM-DD-YY`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Even with `!=` it wouldn't mak much sense. (x != c OR y != c) would only be false if (x=y=c), so the code would basically test that $1 must equal $2 **and** that both parameters should be today's date. If this strange condition is not fulfilled, it would print an _Invalid_ error message.  I don't see the point in this check.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

# validation
for date do
    case $date in
        [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]);;
        *) echo "$date: invalid, must be MM/DD/YYYY" >&2; die=1
    esac
done
[ "$die" ] && exit 1

# sort dates (new to old)
printf '%s\n' "$1" "$2" |
sort -rt / -k 3,3 -k 1,2 |
sed '1ais newer than'
```

Or instead of sort, arrange units largest to smallest, remove non-digits, and compare:

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" "$2" |
{ IFS=/
read m1 d1 y1
read m2 d2 y2
if [ "$y1$m1$d1" -gt "$y2$m2$d2" ]; then
    echo "$1 is newer than $2"
else
    echo "$2 is newer than $1"
fi; }
```

The question isn't tagged bash, so this is POSIX shell. If you can control the date format, you could choose YYYYMMDD, so they can be directly compared (`[ "$1" -gt "$2" ]`).

Comment: I had forgotten that `[ "$1" \> "$2" ]` for a string comparison wasn't POSIX, but you're quite right.